# GeoPandas has new warning and cannot read_file()

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, geopandas

I have written a script long time ago which worked with no problem, using GeoPandas in order to read shapefile to my jupyter notebook.
Today I have run my script and when I import geopandas I get new warning:

```
import geopandas as gpd
```

> PROJ: proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name

seems like the library is being imported, yet I cannot read shapefiles.
This is how I tried to read shapefile:

```
shapes = gpd.read_file('shapefiles/polygons.shp')
```

> CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error:
> proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name)

**I have not changed my script and it worked for long time, so I believe something has changed with the package.  I also used to read this specific shapefile, so nothing has changed in the shapefile itself.**

Has anyone faced the same issue? is something now different with GeoPandas?how can I read the shapefile?

Edit:
geopandas version : 0.9.0

Comment: What is the Geopandas version ?

Comment: It would be helpful to describe your environment. Is this using pip packages? Conda? Other?

Comment: @gene I have edited the original post

Comment: @MikeT I have added the version i'm using in the original post , but i'm not sure how to answer the other questions, I have install packages with pip3 ,and i'm working on jupyterlab server

Comment: PyProj version issue e.g https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/990

Comment: @ThomasG77 I have tried to uninstall and install the pyproj but get this error pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for pyproj==1.9.6

Comment: Did you upgrade your pip version? pip 20.3.4 for me when executing `python3 -m pip --version` Sometimes got install issues due to outdated pip version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just updating if happenns to someone: In the end what worked for me was to uninstall and install again geopandas and pyproj